# Geoserver merker displacement

Tags: geoserver

I am using geoserver styles, and i want to add point layer withe icons like google maps or custom icon,

I made this :

```
          <PointSymbolizer>
           <Graphic>
             <ExternalGraphic>
               <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="administration.png" />
               <Format>image/png</Format>
             </ExternalGraphic>
           </Graphic>                            
         </PointSymbolizer>
```

But it takes the center of icon, how can I make displacement X and Y to take into consideration the top right on my icon for example knowing that the icone has 32x32px

Thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but not very well :

This is :

```
<svg  version="1.1" 
      id="Ebene_1" 
      xmlns="&ns_svg;" 
      xmlns:xlink="&ns_xlink;" 
      width="32" 
      height="74"      
      overflow="visible"       
      xml:space="preserve">

      <image x="0" y="0" width="32" height="37" xlink:href="administration.png" />

</svg>
```

The problem is that the clicked area is big than the visual icon in openlayers.

Any help is very precious